# Different servers handle TTFB vs content download differently

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp, lamp

I have a web page that shows problematic slowness. While debugging it, I have noticed that 90 to 99% of the waiting time is spent on the server after the first request (TTFB), which averages around a horrific 8s. Suspicion goes towards unoptimized queries, lots of inner and outer joins with no proper indexation etc... But this is not the question :)

I have noticed that, on the production server (running Cloudlinux on a dedi box at OVH), for the same TOTAL amount of waiting as on my development machine (Mac OS X running MAMP Pro), the distribution (and behavior) is quite different and wanted to know if anyone knows anything precise about the why:

- CloudLinux server: **12.22s (TTFB) + 2.61ms (Content download)**
- MAMP Pro: **2.36s (TTFB) + 7.46s (Content download)**

Ok, the loads are different between the two servers. But regardless, the pattern is bizarre: on Linux (Apache2 + php 7.3 + MySQL), it seems like the server prepares everything, and when everything is ready, it hands the whole thing to be downloaded, which the browser (Chrome) proceeds doing very quickly.

While on the MAMP server (Apache 2, PHP 7.3, MySQL), it looks like the browser (same Chrome) starts to download and display content even though the server is still working on the remaining of the page.

I am unsure whether this is a behavior set in PHP or Apache configuration, or is inherent to the platform difference. If anyone could point me to the right direction, that would be awesome.

Having the production server behave like my local development machine would be a first step toward making this page a little bit more usable while waiting for the refactoring that is to take place.

EDIT:

To test for PHP buffering the output, I added a .user.ini file with the line `php_value output_buffering Off` in an attempt to turn any buffering, well, off. This had no incidence, the page still displays when all 'work' is done, and TTFB still constitutes 99% of the total waiting time.

Comment: Buffering…? PHP and/or Apache and/or any intervening proxy (CDN?) may be buffering the response before sending it to the browser…

Comment: Interesting, I will dig into that. No CDN is used, it's a straight cloudlinux server serving all assets directly (except the occasional loading js scripts through CDNs for one site or another).

Comment: I added 'php_value output_buffering Off' into a .user.ini file in the site root (that is the way cloudlinux handles .php.ini per user I think) to no avail.

Comment: Additional information request from your OVH server. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I will get that info and edit my question. Just reading your comment was very helpful in a way.

Comment: @Gloria Posting the information requested Feb 6 would allow 'workload tuning analysis'.  I suspect you have been busy with other tasks.

Comment: @Gloria You can determine how 'shared' your hosting ip address has become by running a report at  myip.ms  website. Scroll down the report and the number will be visible on ~ the second page. View my profile, Network profile for free download Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning. If you could post data requested Feb 6, 2020 you will get some suggestions to improve performance.